# Not able to get property of page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

We have Kentico 11.0.26 with MVC

I have a page that I can retrieve like this

```
General mainPage = GeneralProvider.GetGeneral(completeAlias, "en-us", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName)
.Columns("DocumentName", "NodeId", "NodeParentID", "NodeLevel");
```

Now I need to get the sibling pages of this node that may or may not be of the same type.

To preserve the node order I'm trying to get them in one call:

```
var siblings = DocumentHelper
    .GetDocuments()
    .OnSite("mySite")
    .Culture("en-US")
    .Where(d => d.NodeParentID == mainPage.NodeParentID && d.NodeLevel == mainPage.NodeLevel)
    .OrderBy(d => d.NodeOrder)
    .ToList();
```

But I cannot retrieve a field value that exists in only one of the page types. The following throws null reference exception:

```
foreach (var item in siblings)
{
    string colValue = item.GetValue("myColumn").ToString();
}
```

How can I retrieve this field value that exists in only one of the page types (not every sibling may have this column)?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to use both .Types() and .WithCoupledColumns() in the document query to retrieve column values of multiple page types.

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/working-with-pages-in-the-api

```
var siblings = DocumentHelper
                .GetDocuments()
                .Types("MySite.General","MySite.Link")
                .WithCoupledColumns()
                .OnSite("MySite")
                .Culture("en-US")
                .Published();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.TryGetValue](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/10_0/api/html/M_CMS_DocumentEngine_TreeNode_TryGetValue.htm) instead of GetValue

```
var colValue;
item.TryGetValue("myColumn", out colValue);
```

or check classname before and then get value i.e. `item.GetValue("ClassName")`

Comment: Yeah...tried that, and tried using VS debugger. Column value is empty for the correct page type. It is just not being retrieved.

Comment: Oouch Now I understand - you need to do DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().WithCoupledColumns()

Comment: I get this after adding WithCoupledColumns():  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.